# Ошибка с Rigidbody2D (Unity 2019)

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр, unity3d-android

Делаю игру-платформер на юнити, учу все по [уроку](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nak2AOrieTA&t=509s) У меня есть игрок и платформа, оба с коллайдерами, к игроку прикреплен скрипт:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class playerControler : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 20f;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private float moveX;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent <Rigidbody2D> ();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        moveX = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
        rb.MovePosition (rb.position + Vector2.right * moveX * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Но когда я запускаю игру, получаю ошибку:

```
MissingComponentException: There is no 'Rigidbody2D' attached to the "playerSprite" game object, but a script is trying to access it.
You probably need to add a Rigidbody2D to the game object "playerSprite". Or your script needs to check if the component is attached before using it.
UnityEngine.Rigidbody2D.get_position () (at <30c4471525994106ab1e5d6bb9a98850>:0)
playerControler.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/playerControler.cs:17)
```

Помогите пожалуйста, пошарил весь гугл и ничего не нашел...

Answer (score 1):

Нужно добавить Rigidbody 2D на объект на котором "висит" скрипт.